# Equation or approximation of short distance path on Mercator

Tags: distance, wgs84

I use osm map in my project and I want to draw shortest line between two point like this:
[image]

How do they draw this path? Give me please a clue )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer!)
Just need haversine formula to calculate distance in rad, then use formula from here: [Ed Williams, Aviation Formulary](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Intermediate)

Comment: A couple of problems, so far: 1. You don't reproduce any formulas here (what if the link breaks?). 2. The solution gives geographic coords (lat, long) while the questions asks for Mercator (projected) coords.